# why text-decoration: none is not working inside HTML <ins> element

Tags: html, css, web

I will let the code speak. I even try to add `important!` to the css value but still fail to remove line.

Tested in Chrome and Safari.

```css
    .no-decoration {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
  <h1> ins tag</h1>
  <ins>
      <a class="no-decoration" href="">Some link</a>
  </ins>
  
  <h1>no ins tag</h1>
  <div>
      <a class="no-decoration" href="">Some link</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the style for `<ins>` tag also. 
update your CSS with the below code,

```
.no-decoration, ins {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Please check the link https://jsfiddle.net/c1jp3pev/

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `<ins />` tag is decorating it, not the anchor.

```css
    .no-decoration {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
  <h1> ins tag</h1>
  <ins>
      <a class="no-decoration" href="">Some link</a>
      <p>Paragraph of text.</p>
  </ins>
  
  <h1>no ins tag</h1>
  <div>
      <a class="no-decoration" href="">Some link</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the class in a tag and ins tag because both tags produce linked text!

See this for more info! https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ins.asp

Comment: a tag also need the class

Comment: Both a and ins tag produce linked text so you need to style them both

Answer (score 0):

Since,  is used to insert something inside, and it works only with text. But it is possible by using some other tags like  and many more......

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.ins { 
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ins class="ins">Some inserted text.</ins>  <br>

<ins><a href="#" class="ins">Some inserted text.</a></ins>

<div><a href="#" class="ins">Some inserted text.</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```